# SQL query many-to-many: find all items with all tags included in a given set

Tags: sql, sqlite, many-to-many

I'm working with SQLite. Basically, I have a many-to-many relationship between items and tags. I want to find every item such that all its tags are included in a given set (found by another query). So if I have an item with tag1, tag2 and tag3 and the set is only tag1 and tag2, I should not get that item.

I've tried several different approaches, the latest being on the lines of selecting `item_id` such that `COUNT(item_id)` in table `Items_Tags` is equal to `COUNT(item_id)` with the condition `tag IN (tag1, tag2)` (for example). Of course, I'd need to count only the appearances of the current `item_id` and I can't think of a way to do that:

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name FROM Items i
    JOIN Items_Tags it
        ON i.item_id = it.item_id
    WHERE i.item_id IN (
        SELECT item_id FROM Items_Tags
            GROUP BY item_id
            HAVING COUNT(item_id) = (
                SELECT COUNT(item_id) FROM Items_Tags
                    WHERE item_id = current_item_id???
                    AND tag IN (tag1, tag2)
            )
    )
```

I'm sure I'm not tackling this problem in the best possible way since I'm not used to working with SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
To make myself more clear, if there are three items:

- item1 with tags: tag1, tag2
- item2 with tags: tag1, tag2, tag3
- item3 with tags: tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4

And the given set of tags is tag1, tag2 and tag3, I want item1 and item2 to be returned (as all their tags are included in the set), but not item3

Comment: Is there another table `tags` with the names of the tags or does the table `Items_Tags` contain the names of the tags?

Comment: For now, the tags are only in `Items_Tags`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by forpas got me thinking and I came up with another perspective to my problem: I want every item whose tags are all included in a set (from another query), so I actually want all items that are not included among those having a tag that is not included in the set. So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.item_id, i.item_name FROM Items i
    JOIN Items_Tags it
        ON i.item_id = it.item_id
    WHERE i.item_id NOT IN (
        SELECT item_id FROM Items_Tags
            WHERE tag NOT IN (list_of_tags)
    )
```

I will welcome any comments and other answers before accepting this one, in case I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation and having:

```
select it.item_id
from item_tags it
where it.tag in (?, ?)
group by it.item_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

If the items come from another query:

```
with tags as (
      <whatever>
     )
select it.item_id
from item_tags it
where it.tag in (select t.tag from tags t)
group by it.item_id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct tag) from tags);
```

EDIT:

If you want a subset match for the tags, just use:

```
with tags as (
      <whatever>
     )
select it.item_id
from item_tags it left join
     tags t
     on it.tag = t.tag
group by it.item_id
having count(*) = count(it.tag) and
       count(*) >= (select count(distinct tag) from tags);
```

Comment: I don't know the set of tags beforehand, so I can't just compare the count to a fixed number

Comment: @MarioMG . . . You *can*.  You just need to count the values in the query and that depends on how they are passed in.

Comment: The set of tags comes from another, simpler query

Comment: @MarioMG . . . That is easy.  I edited the asnwer.

Comment: It's an interesting approach, but it has one problem: since the `count` is computed after filtering the records with the `where` clause, any item that has more tags than those from the query will be returned. For example, an item with tag1, tag2 and tag3 will be returned if the result of the first query is tag1 and tag2. And that is precisely what I want to avoid.

Comment: @MarioMG . . .  Your original question was not clear on that point, but I see you edited it.  I modified the answer.

Comment: An exact match is no good either. Notice that if an item has tag1 and tag2, and the set is tag1, tag2 and tag3, the item *should* be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables, group by item and use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
WITH tags_list(tag) AS (VALUES ('tag1'), ('tag2'))
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name
FROM Items i JOIN Items_Tags it 
ON i.item_id = it.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id, i.item_name
HAVING SUM(it.tag NOT IN tags_list) = 0
```

Or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH tags_list(tag) AS (VALUES ('tag1'), ('tag2'))
SELECT i.item_id, i.item_name
FROM Items i 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Items_Tags it 
  WHERE it.item_id = i.item_id
    AND it.tag NOT IN tags_list
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=cd4d9ac0c8176687e441dcb170bbc15b).

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand the first approach. However, if as you say it returns items with an exact match to the list of tags, it will skip those with less tags. For example, an item with tag1 and tag2 should be returned if the list is comprised of tag1, tag2 and tag3.
I think the second approach is closer to what I'm looking for, and it actually gave me an idea that I will publish as a self-answer.

Comment: @MarioMG *it will skip those with less tags*, it is not clear in your question that you want these items returned. For this case the solution is simpler. See my edited answer.